# Drools Rules Fireing Order when Fact data changes

Tags: drools

I am new to Drools and either I misunderstand what Drools can do or I am missing something.

I have a simple Fact class

```
public class MeterReadTO {

private String status = "";

public String getStatus() {
  return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
   this.status = status;
}

public boolean isInvalid() {
  return status.equals("invalid");
};

}
```

With the rules

```
 rule "Rule Invalid"

 dialect "mvel"
 when
     MeterReadTO( isInvalid());
 then
  System.out.println("Rule Invalid Fired");

end

rule "Rule Not Invalid"

 dialect "mvel"
when
   not MeterReadTO(  isInvalid());
then
   System.out.println("Rule Not Invalid Fired");

end

rule "Set Status"

 dialect "mvel"
 when
    $mr: MeterReadTO()
  then
      System.out.println("Rule Set Status Fires");

     modify($mr) {
      setStatus("invalid")
     }
   end
```

and I run the rules with

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class Dependancy {


static KieSession ksession;

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Dependancy.class);


MeterReadTO mr;


@BeforeClass
public static void start() {


      KieContainer kieClasspathContainer = KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
        ksession = kieClasspathContainer.newKieSession("DependancyTest");
}

@Test
public void contextLoadsAndRetrievesData() {

    MeterReadTO mr = new MeterReadTO();
    mr.setId(50);

    ksession.insert(mr);

    // when
    ksession.fireAllRules();
    ksession.dispose();

    // Then
    System.out.println("After Drools, status is " + mr.getStatus());

}
```

}

and I get the outcome

```
Rule Not Invalid Fired
Rule Set Status Fires
After Drools, status is invalid
```

By using a stateful session I was expecting to see the "rule Invalid" fire after "rule Set Status" fires. If I move the Set Status rule from the bottom of the list of rules to the top, then I get

```
Rule Set Status Fires
Rule Not Invalid Fired
After Drools, status is invalid
```

So clearly Drools is not aware of the status change in rule Set Status. What am I missing?

Regards

FOLLOW UP.

Now I'm really confused. If I remove the call to the method isInvalid() in my rules file and reference the getStatus() method instead so the rules now look like

```
rule "Rule Invalid"

dialect "mvel"
when
  MeterReadTO( getStatus() == "ïnvalid");
then
  System.out.println("Rule Invalid Fired");

end

rule "Rule Not Invalid"

 dialect "mvel"
 when
   MeterReadTO( getStatus() == "");
 then
    System.out.println("Rule Not Invalid Fired");

end

rule "Set Status"

dialect "mvel"

when
    $mr: MeterReadTO()
  then
      System.out.println("Rule Set Status Fires");

  modify($mr) {
    setStatus("ïnvalid")
  }

   end
```

Then I get the output that I expected

```
Rule Not Invalid Fired
Rule Set Status Fires
Rule Invalid Fired
After Drools, status is ïnvalid
```

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what's happening is that there is no way for Drools to understand that when you change the `status` of your fact, the result of the method `isInvalid()` is affected.

When you modify a fact, Drools will try to minimize the reevaluation of the rules as much as possible. In your case, Drools has no way to make a connection between the `setStatus()` and `isInvalid()` methods.

In the second case, you are using the `getStatus()` method in your rules and Drools is then able to do the connections (by simple POJO naming conventions).

One way to make sure Drools understands the connection between `setStatus()` and `isInvalid()` could be to use the `@watch` annotation in your rule:

```
rule "Rule Invalid"
 dialect "mvel"
 when
   MeterReadTO( isInvalid()) @watch(status)
 then
  System.out.println("Rule Invalid Fired");
end

rule "Rule Not Invalid"
dialect "mvel"
when
  not MeterReadTO(  isInvalid()) @watch(status)
then
  System.out.println("Rule Not Invalid Fired");
end
```

The problem with this approach is that your rules get really tied to your model. If the way you check whether a fact is invalid ahs to be modified to involve more fields, you has to go rule by rule modifying the `@watch` annotation.

Another solution would be to mark the relationship in the model itself using the `@Modifies` annotation:

```
public class MeterReadTO {
  private String status = "";

  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  @Modifies( { "invalid" } )
  public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  public boolean isInvalid() {
    return status.equals("invalid");
  };

}
```

You can find more information about this topic in [Drools' official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_fine_grained_property_change_listeners).

Hope it helps,

Comment: As a follow up, if I make status a boolean and use the POJO methods setStatus() and isStatus() then everything also works as expected